# Making grid cell content fill the cell, without losing flow layout

Tags: css, css-grid

**I have this code for a grid:**

```css
  .cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15em);
  padding: 0.5em;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.cards>div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div>
    <h2>
      <div class="logo">LOGO<br>LOGO</div>Title</h2>
    <p>Some content made from some words</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some content<br>Some more<br>Even more</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Edited: div class=logo instead of aside*

**When you try this, you see:**

- the LOGO extends into the p element and displaces its content. That's good, I want that
- the p element of the second card is higher and determines the height of the grid row. That's good, I want that
- the p element of the first card does not reach the bottom of the card. That's normal, but I want to change that.

How to make the smaller p to fill the room under the heading? Flexbox is not an option, because flex items create block formatting contexts, causing the h2 height to increase. I do not want that!

I could use JavaScript to achieve this. But you shouldn't use JavaScript when pure CSS will do. But does it? I don't find a solution.

Comment: So what should this look like? Should the font-size increase, letter spacing? Or is this just a background color issue?

Comment: Side note: `aside` is not a valid child element inside a `h2` element. `aside` is only allowed to be placed in elements that accept **flow content**, which h2 is not!

Comment: *Flexbox is not an option, because flex items create block formatting contexts, causing the h2 height to increase.* --> what do you mean by this? Creating a BFC has nothing to do with height

Comment: But it has to to with float containment. A float can hang out of a normal div, but not if it's a flex oder grid item. Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/uL6fxyvr/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D: The problem I intend to solve is content alignment. I want to be able to align something to the card bottom. For this, the element under the title (be it a p or a div class="content") needs to filll the card. My real HTML is more complex, I simplified it to concentrate on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i can think of with CSS is to set the height of p to 100% and set the card div overflow to hidden. It's seems to be ok (at least for this example)

```css
.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15em);
  padding: 0.5em;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.cards>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div>
    <h2>
      <div class="logo">LOGO<br>LOGO</div>Title</h2>
    <p>Some content made from some words</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some content<br>Some more<br>Even more</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cards">
  <div>
    <h2>
      <div class="logo">LOGO<br>LOGO</div>Title</h2>
    <p>Some content made from some words</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>This is a very long title to test if it overflow</h2>
    <p>Some content<br>Some more<br>Even more<br>Even more<br>Even more<br>Last</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I am not sure is it what u want but let's try.

So I thought why u can't use simple **height:100%** for **p** element?

But then I understand that height is starts stick out of div and that's because when you set height to 100%, it is calculated based on the height of its main container excluding the padding and you got 0.5em padding on **.card**

So I try to fit it just by changing the % of heigh and it's work pretty nice when I set it in something like 76%. But? But what if the content change? It's doesn't work good any more.

The solution for this is calc function. It can help subtract the padding from 100% height. You can try something like this:

```
height: calc(100% - 1.75em)
```

It's fill almost 100% of the div and it's works when height is changed by content.

The final CSS:

```
.cards {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2,15em);
padding: 0.5em;
gap: 0.5em;
}
.cards &gt; div {
border: 1px solid blue;
}
h2 {
margin: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
aside {
float:right;
border: 1px solid red;
}
p {
margin: 0;
background-color: yellow;
height: calc(100% - 1.75em)
}
```

Comment: `height: 100% ` means 100% of the parent's height. However, this code uses CSS-Grid which has a completely different case. The main reason that he has some issues with his code is the invalid usage of `aside` inside `h2` which on top of that is floated instead of aligned with flexbox or grid itself.

Comment: I agree, aside is a bad idea here, because of semantics. From layout perspective, it's the same as div. So please assume that I used <div class="logo"> instead; I'll edit the question.
I want to keep the float, to allow logos higher than the title. I could use an absolute element, but that would not displace the texts. I can't calculate the content height because I don't know the title height. It can occupy 2 lines, even depending on screen size (card width is responsive). Without the logo, a flexbox would be just the solution. But with that, the floated logo doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score -3):

**try this one**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
          .cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 15em);
  padding: 0.5em;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.cards>div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

.logo {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards">
        <div>
          <h2>
            <div class="logo">LOGO<br>LOGO</div>Title</h2>
          <p>Some content <br> made from <br>some words</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Some content<br>Some more<br>Even more</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't pay attention to what you copied? That's my own code.

Comment: Adding a few <br> in the text is not a solution...If the example text contains sentences instead of a list of words it no longer works.
HTML is not supposed to define formatting.

Comment: Ah, I missed that little change :)
And no, that is definitely not helpful. (a) I don't want to adjust my content and (b) because of responsiveness the grid column count can change, and so the neighbours.
Either it has to be some CSS declaration voodoo, or I must monitor the sizes with script.